# Why is MultipartFile null on POST mockMvc Test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-restcontroller

When passing in a MockMultiPartFile into my POST request via MockMvc it is coming into my controller as null when the file is being populated correctly in setup step.

CONTROLLER:

```
  @PostMapping(path = MANUAL_TRIGGER)
  private @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> bpsDataLoad(
      @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile positionFile) throws IOException {
```

TEST:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class BPSDataLoadControllerTest {

  @Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  @Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}")
  String defaultSchema;

  MockMultipartFile file;
  MockMultipartFile invalidFile;
  Path path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/testdata/oneposition.txt");
  Path invalidPath =
      Paths.get("src/test/resources/testdata/invalidposition.txt");
  String name = "file.txt";
  String originalFileName = "file.txt";
  String contentType = "text/plain";
  byte[] content = null;
  byte[] invalidContent = null;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    try {
      content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      invalidContent = Files.readAllBytes(invalidPath);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
    file = new MockMultipartFile(name, originalFileName, contentType, content);
    invalidFile = new MockMultipartFile(name, originalFileName, contentType, invalidContent);

    JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, defaultSchema + ".bps_position_table");
  }

  @Test
  @Disabled("File is coming in as null, works on smoke test.")
  public void bpsDataLoadTestOK() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
        .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/perform-bpsLoad").file(file))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"));
  }
```

I have tried using the `@WebApplicationContext` way of initializing mockMvc variable instead of @Autowiring it in like I've seen in other answers for testing .multipart() function, but the file coming in was still null, causing the assertion to fail as the response was not a 200 due to the file being null.

Previous Attempt:

```
MockMvc mockMvc 
  = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
mockMvc.perform(multipart("/perform-bpsLoad").file(file))
  .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Any update, I ran into this issue today.